# What's the most regular value for returning?

Tags: c#, double, area

I just want to ask you: I have a method that calculates a triangle area with 3 parameters - the sides of the triangle. The returning type of the method is double. So if the sum of every 2 sides is lower than the third one, I have to return a value. What is the most regular value for returning in the wrong case? I suggest for now that `double.NaN` is the best practise.

```
public static double CalculateTriangleArea(double firstSide, double secondSide, double thirdSide)
{
   bool areSidesPositive = (firstSide <= 0) || (secondSide <= 0) || (thirdSide <= 0);
   if (areSidesPositive)
   {
      double halfPerimeter = (firstSide + secondSide + thirdSide) / 2;
      double area = Math.Sqrt(halfPerimeter * (halfPerimeter - firstSide) * (halfPerimeter - secondSide) * (halfPerimeter - thirdSide));

      return area;
   }

   return double.NaN;
 }
```

Comment: You could throw an `ArgumentException` if these are invalid arguments.

Comment: +1 to the argument exception. You should not return a value if your method cannot be executed, that's what ArgumentException is for!

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't agree with  argument exception  as it add an addition overhead he can  use a try with  a boolean returned value

Comment: @K.B: depends on how _invalid_ the arguments are and how often that happens. You could create a `TryCalculateTriangleArea` with a `bool` as return value and a `double` as `out` parameter, so the `TryParse`-pattern.

Comment: I knew that this is the right way but I didn't mention that you can throw an exception without returning any value. Now I just replaced return double.NaN with ArgumentException without recieving a compilation error. Thank you so much.

Comment: @TimSchmelter this what I  have suggested as an answer

Comment: @StanimirYakimov: instead of throwing the exception at a final step you should throw it as quick as possible, so best at the top of the method body. The reason is that you are in danger of calculating with invalid arguments otherwise.

Comment: @TimSchmelter is the reason  why microsoft suggested tryparse for all primitive types instead of parse only

Comment: I think your logic is incorrect regarding `areSidesPositive`, I think you meant to say: `bool areSidesPositive = firstSide >= 0 && secondSide >= 0 && thirdSide >= 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
    return default(double);
```

Comment: I was thinking OP should consider `0` when area is not positive. For the case of invalid argument returning default value is not appropriate. Your suggestion of throwing `ArgumentException` is more appropriate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use double value to return in your case like this:

```
return default(double);
```

Also as suggested by Tim it would be better to throw `ArgumentException` if it is an invalid arguments.

```
public static double CalculateTriangleArea(double firstSide, double secondSide, double thirdSide)
{
   bool areSidesPositive = (firstSide <= 0) || (secondSide <= 0) || (thirdSide <= 0);
   if (areSidesPositive)
   {
      double halfPerimeter = (firstSide + secondSide + thirdSide) / 2;
      double area = Math.Sqrt(halfPerimeter * (halfPerimeter - firstSide) * (halfPerimeter - secondSide) * (halfPerimeter - thirdSide));

      return area;
   }

   throw new ArgumentException("Argument not correct",
                                    firstSide,secondSide, thirdSide);
 }
```

Comment: This will return `0` which is not true in case the shape is not a triangle.

Answer (score 1):

One suggested answer could be

```
public static bool TryCalculateTriangleArea(double firstSide, double secondSide, double thirdSide,out double rArea)
    {
        bool areSidesPositive = (firstSide <= 0) || (secondSide <= 0) || (thirdSide <= 0);
        if (areSidesPositive)
        {
            double halfPerimeter = (firstSide + secondSide + thirdSide) / 2;
            double area = Math.Sqrt(halfPerimeter * (halfPerimeter - firstSide) * (halfPerimeter - secondSide) * (halfPerimeter - thirdSide));

            rArea= area;
  return  true ;  
        }

        return  false  
    }
```

Comment: I can't change the returning type.

Comment: @StanimirYakimov: do you know that you still get the `double` value which was calculated in the `out`-parameter?

Comment: @StanimirYakimov "I can't change the returning type". what's the reason ?

Comment: O, yeah I just saw it. I have to scroll to the right.

Comment: Because it's refactoring exercise and It's specified in requirements.

Comment: I think is the best moment to do as I  have mentioned above is the reason why microsoft suggested tryparse for all primitive types instead of parse only

Answer (score 1):

You code is wrong, you should have `if (!areSidesPositive)` instead of `if (areSidesPositive)` ... Your code will never be executed even with good parameters. 
AND yes, throw an ArgumentException it's the best way to proceed.

Comment: Yes but now his logic is wrong. `areSidesPositive` returns the wrong result.

Comment: Yep, I agree. The bool name should be `areSidesNegative` if he wants to keep his code.

Answer (score 0):

By passing in one side longer than the other two combined, you are *violating a (implicit) precondition of your function*, so I would suggest throwing an `ArgumentException` instead of returning a value.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case there is no need to do anything:

```
public static double CalculateTriangleArea(double firstSide, double secondSide, double thirdSide)
{
    double halfPerimeter = (firstSide + secondSide + thirdSide) / 2;
    return Math.Sqrt(halfPerimeter * (halfPerimeter - firstSide) * (halfPerimeter - secondSide) * (halfPerimeter - thirdSide));
}
```

Point is [`Math.Sqrt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sqrt.aspx) will return `NaN`/`+Infinity` if arguments are wrong (it's exception free method). You have to check returned value (if it's `NaN` or `+Infinity`) before using it.

Other possible approach would be to throw exception (`ArugmentException`? `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`? `YourOwnException`? whatever) to clearly break program flow in case if arguments are wrong. Despite overhead, it could be a preferred way in scenario of having several operations related to each other. `If` is faster, but generalizing error (displaying `"Something is wrong"` message) could be better if you don't really care what exactly was wrong, simply want to break the flow.